# How to create a pan and zoom canvas (like Photoshop) in Cocoa

Tags: swift, cocoa, uiscrollview, nsview, nsscrollview

I'm working on a really simple drawing app for Mac in Cocoa, and playing around with `NSScrollView` to create a drawing canvas that dynamically resizes, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I want to have an `NSView` that grows in size when I scroll around (pan) and also increases in size when I zoom out. Obviously I'd set a maximum size for the canvas to put limits on memory, but just have no idea where to start.

Any thoughts? Also, Any ideas for iOS or UIKit solution? I can adapt as needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a ScrollView or UIScrollView would require increasing its size whenever I scrolled, and slowed my app down incredibly. I looked at using a tiled scrollview, but this also just created a massive scrollview.

What I ended up doing was creating a 'canvas' view, which could then be manipulated by the user. When they wanted to zoom, this 'canvas' was simply scaled to created the illusion of zooming, when they wanted to pan around the infinite work area, the canvas just moved to create the illusion of panning.

Basically, I was creating the illusion of an infinite canvas by allowing the user to move the object of interest around in a finite NSView, with the ability to move it off screen, and back on screen when they needed to.

Comment: I’m looking to implement something similar. Do you have any code snippets you could share?

Comment: Can you share a bit of code? I want to implement the same functionality. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

Seems you are looking for a tutorial for using `UIScrollView` or `NSScrollView` here! (you'd be better do it on Google)

To use `UIScrollView` you have to conform to `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol then implement required functions. You can find a detailed instruction [here](http://www.appcoda.com/uiscrollview-introduction/).

Comment: Yup. I know all about Scrollviews and delegates, hence me asking here.